# String Boot getting a resource file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, file-io

I have a Spring Boot app. that contains this file:

```
resources/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx
```

and in the code:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx")
private Resource telefonicaMetricsTemplate;

..

Workbook wb = 
            WorkbookFactory.create
            (telefonicaMetricsTemplate.getInputStream());
```

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/telefonicaUtils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
```

I also tried `Resource telefonicaMetricsTemplate = new ClassPathResource("/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx");` with the same result

I am running the app. from the command line as follows:

```
java -jar target/telefonicaUtils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I running the app. from Eclipse and it works fine

Comment: Did yo try classpath*:/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx , to search for every metrics directory on the classpath?

Comment: if you specify `"classpath:/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx"`, I think that checks in root on your filesystem. Maybe try removing the first slash, since typically the resources folder is considered by your IDE to be `.` (at least thats how intelliJ does it.)  So you could try `"classpath:metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx"` or `"classpath:./metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx"` or `"file:metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx"` or `"file:./metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are hardcoding you resource path, you ain't need any dependency injection. Just initialize your resource as a `ClassPathResource`:

```
private Resource telefonicaMetricsTemplate = new ClassPathResource("/metrics/telefonica/Metrics.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing `classpath:...` with `file:...` and specifying an absolute path?

Also, I know there is an Apache API for handling Microsoft documents. You can use it with your Spring Boot app and make your own `Resource` bean: https://poi.apache.org/

example of usage: https://www.concretepage.com/apache-api/read-write-and-update-xlsx-using-poi-in-java